# FileIO exception when sending a sms message

Tags: android, sms-gateway

My friend needs help with her thesis. She's making an Android app that uses a sms gateway (she's using a [sms gateway by wavecell](https://developer.wavecell.com/v1/api-documentation/send-sms-single) for this). But when she submits a text message, it gives an error about a FileIO exception. I already tried checking and giving her suggestions but I don't have much experience with using a sms gateway so I'm not sure if I missed something.

She says her balance for the service is still enough and hasn't expired yet. She's also tried generating a new access token and changing the inputs required to hardcoded values but it's still not working.

Here's the code:

```
package com.example.johnica.mysmsgateway;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Response;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button send;
    EditText number, message1;

    final int SEND_SMS_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        send=findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
        message1=findViewById(R.id.inputMessage);
        number=findViewById(R.id.inputNumber);

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    // Construct data

                    String text = "&text=" + message1.getText().toString();
                    String source = "&source=" + "Take Care";
                    String destination = "&destination=" + number.getText().toString();

                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://api.wavecell.com/sms/v1/{sub account id here}/single").openConnection();

                    String data = destination + text + source;

                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer {used a token here}");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(data.length()));
                    conn.getOutputStream().write(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                    final BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    final StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,line.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    rd.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy st= new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(st);

    }
}
```

When the send button is pressed, the stacktrace produces `JAVA IO file not found exception url https://developer.wavecell.com/v1/sms-api`

Comment: "it gives an error about a FileIO exception" -- if you can, get the stack trace associated with that exception and add it to the question.

Comment: @CommonsWare i just added the stacktrace output

Comment: Sounds like the app cannot reach that server, perhaps due to a firewall or similar issue. You might also consider using a more modern HTTP client API, such as OkHttp.

Comment: oh i see. i'll ask her to update the post request method and and check her firewall. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CommonsWare suggested, working with a more modern HTTP client API worked (in this case, OkHttp was used).